# Inheritance doesn't work with multidimensional array

Tags: c#, inheritance, multidimensional-array

i try to get multidimensional array from scriptA in scriptB using inheritance and it seems like after calling this array on scriptB, array is empty.

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected GameObject[,] boardFields = new GameObject[8, 8];

    void Awake()
    {
        boardFields[4, 0] = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Board/Fields/A4");
        Debug.Log(boardFields[4, 0]); //here i see in the console that the variable is not empty
        //rest of the code
    }
}

public class ScriptB : ScriptA
{
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(boardFields[4, 0]); //and here i get null in the console
    }
}
```

I also checked another variables and it seems that the problem is only with multidimensional array. Singledimensional arrays work normally, same as int, float, string etc.. How can i solve this trouble?

P.S: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: There's nothing special about multidimensional arrays in this sense. They don't break inheritance. You probably are working with multiple instances, where in one you assign it in instance 1 and look access its items in instance 2, which will have all nulls.

Comment: @CodeCaster can You tell my how i should do it? or link to someone blog/documentation where this is explained. I search so many blogs and tuts and still don't know how to do it. Sorry i just started with object programming.

Comment: You need to debug and check that Awake() is called.

Comment: I already solve my problem, thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your `Awake` method `protected`. E.g.

```
protected void Awake(){
// etc.
}
```

Unity cannot find the `Awake` method on the inherited class, since `private` methods are hidden by default. You should find that you only get one debug log (from Start()), and not the expected two (the other being from the base class Awake()). When you fix this, you should get two logs, and the array won't be null.

Comment: why would `Start` trigger? as it is also not declared `protected`.

Comment: Start triggers regardless of the protection level. When you inherit from a class, all private members of the class you inherit from become hidden. Basically, Unity can trigger anything that you can access within the class. Since you can access Start from within, Unity can call it. However, Awake is inaccessible since it is privately declared in the base class, and so Unity cannot access it.

Comment: @Number3434 i got two logs in console, from `Awake()` and `Start()`

Comment: Then it should be working. :)

Comment: it didn't work then, but i make another protected function and it's work. Thanks for help anyway

Comment: This is not really true actually. `Awake` will also be called if it is `private`! Those are not called as normal messages but via a message system (kinda similar to reflection though not the same). It is still good practice though because the issues really kick in if you re-declare another `Awake` method in the inheritor later ;) If you know you will have inheritors of your class always make those Unity messages `protected virtual`!